# Clojure generator function

Tags: clojure, closures, generator

I use this function to create a new function which returns a new position for where to place content in a PDF.

The generator must return the new line position for each call. But it must also be able to be reset to a certain value.

```clj
(defn pos-generator [initial-val delta] 
    (let [counter (ref initial-val)]
         (fn ([] (dosync (let [cur-val @counter] 
                             (do (alter counter + delta)
                                 cur-val))))
             ([new-val] (dosync (ref-set counter new-val))
                                 ))))


; example usage:
(let [ypos (pos-generator 470 -15)]
     (add-to-pdf "bla bla"    [290 y])
     (add-to-pdf "bla bla"    [290 y]))
```

But it seems a little awkward, is there a more ideomatic Clojure way?

Comment: use `(def y-position (atom initial-val))` and `swap!` `reset!` functions

Comment: You are not using the `ypos` generator function in your usage example. Shouldn't `(add-to-pdf "bla bla" [290 y])` actually be `(add-to-pdf "bla bla" [290 (ypos)])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `atom` as edbond suggested results in more idiomatic code IMO, since you don't really need synchronization between two or more `ref`s, but only a *place* to store a changing value.

```
(defn pos-generator [initial-val delta] 
  (let [counter (atom initial-val)]
    (fn
      ([]
        (let [cur-val @counter]
          (swap! counter + delta)
          cur-val))
      ([new-val]
        (reset! counter new-val)))))

(let [ypos (pos-generator 470 -15)]
  [[290 (ypos)]
   [290 (ypos)]
   [290 (do (ypos 20) (ypos))]
   [290 (ypos)]])

;= [[290 470] [290 455] [290 20] [290 5]]
```

As a side note, there's no need to use `do` within code inside a `let` form, it is already treated the same way as in `do`.